# Change Font Background Color in Graphics2D

Tags: fonts, background-color, graphics2d

I'm drawing various strings in a Graphics2d using Graphics2D.drawString(). This works fine, but I can't seem to change the background color of the strings; it always uses the initial (in this case, white) background color when rendering.

I can simulate this effect by getting the font's bounding box, drawing a filled rectangle based on its size at a location dredged from the font's baseline position and height, but this is unpleasant and, at least in my case, not quite right - the alignment of the filled rectangle relative to the text is slightly too high.

Can't I just call g2d.setBackground(color) prior to my drawString() call?

Answer (score 0):

I could be getting this wrong, but are you trying to change the text color or the background behind the text?

If you're just changing the text color, all you need is

```
g2d.setColor(Color.RED); //or whatever your desired color is
```

before whatever text you're drawing.

I'm not aware of a way to set a background behind the text besides just filling a rectangle behind the text.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No. DrawString does not fill the text background. Instead, you can draw a filled rectangle before DrawString. As you mentioned, it doesn't always look quite right. One way the works OK is to use g2d.MeasureString to get the text rectangle, then expand it a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try setForeground(Color)

Comment: Graphics2D does not have a setForeground() method.